# Font measurement points in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I ran on one problem.

When I set the font size of any node with CSS, no matter what measurement unit I choose (I tried both pt and px), font size is still set in pixels.
I also tried to set font for “Text” with the method “setFont”, which accepts parameter of type “Font”.

It is said in JavaFX2 documentation, that:

> The size of a Font is described as being specified in points which
>   are a real world measurement of approximately 1/72 inch.

But the font size was still set in pixels.

For an experiment I added “WebView” to the scene and loaded a page in it, on which I displayed two div tags. Within the first div the font size was in pt, and within the second one – in px. As I had suggested, the font sizes were different, and the font size in the last div was identical to the font size in the nodes I referred to at the beginning.

Why is this happening? How do I set the font size in pt? At this moment to solve this problem I convert pt to px using this formula: px=pt/0.75 (dpi of my screen is 96).

[image]

example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontSmoothingType;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;

public class TestFont extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final Group root = new Group();
        Scene s = new Scene(root, 500, 500);


        Text t = new Text(100, 250, "1) - abcdeABCDE12");
        t.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.LCD);
        t.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 36pt; -fx-font-family: Calibri;");
        Text t2 = new Text(100, 300, "2) - abcdeABCDE12");
        t2.setFont(javafx.scene.text.Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.REGULAR, 36));
        t2.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.GRAY);
        Text t3 = new Text(100, 350, "3) - abcdeABCDE12");
        t3.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 36px; -fx-font-family: Calibri;");;
        t3.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.GRAY);

        WebView wv = new WebView();
        wv.setLayoutX(100);
        wv.setLayoutY(360);
        URL urlWebViewCell = this.getClass().getResource("/testFont.html");
        wv.getEngine().load(urlWebViewCell.toExternalForm());

        root.getChildren().addAll(wv, t, t2, t3);

        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

testFont.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div style="font-size: 36pt; font-family: Calibri;">4) - abcdeABCDE12</div>
<div style="font-size: 36px; font-family: Calibri;">5) - abcdeABCDE12</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by applying the style the method Font.font(String, double) "only" searches for a font (btw the Font Constructor uses the same size parameter) and is always using the double value as a size value in pixels. So there is no way to choose what measurement you want to have.

So your current why is the best.
But you can use:

```
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
```

to become independent of the resolution.